# Why is URL with a port number in my MVC 4 app giving me "A potentially dangerous Request.Path value " error?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've deployed an MVC 4 app to IIS - the url has a port number. The app is actually upgraded from the MVC 3 to MVC 4.
When I browse to the app I get

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).
```

This seems to be suggesting that the colon (which is required for the port number in the url) is the problem.

I've tried adding this to my config

```
<httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
<pages validateRequest="false" />
```

This doesn't help.

Comment: This is embarrassing, please close - my hosts file was botched meaning that the url was pointing to a remote machine instead of localhost.

Comment: bplus that will hurt you, you could put that as the answer and accept it.  I doubt you're alone in that mistake and it might help someone else.